# HTML beautifier that puts input tags on separate lines

Tags: ruby, htmltidy

I have to work with some really ugly looking markup and I am running it through Tidy on ruby. For the most part it works great except for the fact that it lumps a ton of hidden inputs that are in the markup on to one line. I know there is a setting for a column wrap but it would be nicer if it just put sibling inputs on separate lines. It is important because it would simplify debugging when looking at the markup and seeing the info quickly in those hidden inputs.

I have yet to find a tool that does this. So is there anything out there or am I being foolish?

I should also add that a lot of the issues stem from the bad markup I get initially and there is nothing I can do to clean it up before it gets to me. I tried Nokogiri-pretty to clean it up and it was so close to being perfect but it turned script tags in to self closing tags which is no good.

Right now I am settling with Tidying the source and then (I know this is terrible) `gsub(/<input[^>]*>/, '\0'+"\n")`. I love the fact that I had to concat the capture with the newline.

Answer (score 2):

Tidy tends to be problematic in Ruby. It has been [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423932/182590) to leak memory, it isn't 1.9 compatible, etc. However, you may be able to skip Tidy altogether by using Nokogiri and the `nokogiri-pretty` gem.

Assuming you have a Nokogiri doc:

```
require 'nokogiri-pretty'
puts doc.human
```

In addition to other tidying, all `<input>` tags will be on their own line and properly indented.

Comment: It was so close. Nokogiri Pretty made empty script tags self closing which broke a lot of stuff.

Comment: Why do you have empty script tags?

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri can do that easy enough:

```
doc.css('input').each{|input| input.before "\n"}
```