# Rails - close html tags when you enter html in a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way to close html tags if a user forgets to? E.g. when the user input is:

```
<b>small</b><i>test
```

Is there a way in Rails to automatically add the closing `</i>` tag, so that all the following html won't be italic?

I used `.html_safe` to interpret everything as html, but I would like to terminate `<i>` too.

Comment: Do you realize it's very unsafe to use `.html_safe` on user input? Try to read up on [Cross-site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 4):

Rails doesn't have any built in capability to do this however you have a couple of options:

1. Nokogiri - easy to install on pretty much all platforms (`gem install nokogiri`)
2. [Tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308713/html-tidy-cleaning-in-ruby-1-9) - The second post has the details to use it in linux and windows

Using nokogori you can simply do:

```
html = "<b>small</b><i>test"
clean = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html).to_html
# clean = "<b>small</b><i>test</i>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails can't do that to you.

You can use some template system like Haml or Slim to don't forget that.

You can do it by your own editor too.

Answer (score 0):

A decent way to do this would be to feed the input to a dom parser and then have that parser output correct HTML.

Note that this isn't fool proof and if the user makes too many mistakes, the parser won't know what to do.

I'd suggest [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)